# init() method calls on every request

Tags: jsf, servlets, jsf-2, liferay

I am using JSF 2.0 and Liferay 6.1

On any kind of request to any Java class my `init()` is getting called. Even in case of PrimeFaces component calls for its related PrimeFaces Java method. This method should be called only once when my portlet will initialize.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyMangedBean {

    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Init method called");
    }
}
```

Please help me to find out possible solution.

**EDIT**

I found the component behind this cause

In my xhtml file I have

```
<bridge:inputFile id="MyFileUpload" size="50"
            binding="#{myBean.toBeUploadFile}" onchange="{fileSelected(this);}" style="position: absolute;height: 29px;width:107px;opacity:0;filter: alpha(opacity=0);z-index:100;"/>
```

Whenever I remove its binding attribute. My project works fine. It will not call init() multiple times. But I need this attribute to get my file uploaded.

I have kept xml namespace as

```
xmlns:bridge="http://portletfaces.org/bridge"
```

I have also kept dependency for commons-io(version 1.3) and commons-filedownload(1.2.1) in pom.xml

I dont know what else I am missing for this component or what is actual cause behind this.

Comment: How are you referencing that method?

Comment: This method will be called when my JSF portlet should be initialized after that it should not called. But in my case after initialization any call or request to any other backend java method are calling this method.

Comment: The given code is not enough to understand your concrete issue, which seems to be related to how liferay is managing the bean.

Comment: Yeah but I actually dont know which part of my code I should provide. Since I cant put my all code.

Comment: Somewhere you should have a reference to your init() method. Either in your liferay configuration or in your JSF views.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Hi I found the component behind it. In my xhtml I have <bridge:inputFile id="MyFileUpload" size="50"
    binding="#{myBean.servReqFile}" onchange="{fileSelected(this);}" "/>  After removing this binding attribute its works fine. But I need this binding attribute to upload my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using the bridge:inputFile tag that comes with the latest release of [Liferay Faces](https://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/overview) instead of the older obsolete tags that come from portletfaces.org.

There is [a nice demo here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/liferay/faces/demos/jsf2-portlet/3.1.3-ga4/jsf2-portlet-3.1.3-ga4.war) that uses the bridge:inputFile that you can try on a Liferay tomcat portal instance, and then follow the same [pattern that it uses for file upload](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces/blob/3.1.x/demos/bridge/jsf2-portlet/src/main/webapp/views/applicant.xhtml#L136).

That demo has been tested, it works great, and it is supported by Liferay.

There are many more demos that are tested and working well on Liferay Portal 6.1.  You can download the source for them and [build them for yourself as shown here](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Building+Liferay+Faces+From+Source).  And follow [the version scheme here](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+Faces+Version+Scheme) to make sure that you align the correct versions of the Portal, Mojarra, and the Liferay Faces Bridge.

Hope that helps.